# Rails: Assets/stylesheets/application.scss formatting not applied to view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

This is my application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.fav_yes {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation {
  color:green;
};
```

Yet when I have elements with class="fav_yes" in my views I'm still not seeing the styled html. I tried messing around with semicolons and whatnot with no luck. No similar questions seem to provide effective solutions. What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the extension of your file to `application.css.scss`.

Comment: This didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bootstrap-saas git-hub write up:

> If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it:

I still had an application.css file, so the .scss was being overriden. I just copied and pasted content of the .scss into .css, deleted the .scss file and renamed the the .css file to .scss.

Comment: is it solved ? the trick was indeed to just rename your application.css, to application.css.scss ! not create an other one. and as @Marv-C said, don't forget to add _//= require bootstrap-sprockets_ under _//= require jquery_ in your application.js file

Comment: Great dont forget to mark your own answer as best answer ;) I suggested a slight edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add this to your application.js: **//= require bootstrap-sprockets**

make sure it is under //= require jquery